# Replacing separator

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible to replace last separator `|` character with space on each row using notepad++ only if the `|` is between the `name` and `secondname`?

I have:

```
number|surname|name
number|surname|name|secondname
```

I need:

```
number|surname|name
number|surname|name secondname
```

Comment: Why is the last separator in the first line not replaced?

Comment: As it can be surename|name and surename|name|secondname and I need replace then only surename|name|secondname is not for surename|name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, you can use this regex

```
((?:\w+\|){2})(\w+)\|(\w+)
```

and replace with `$1$2 $3`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fH1sW0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm making the assumption that you have a pipe delimited file that you need to 'fix' so that there is a correct amount of columns and that there are 3 columns, with the problem being that the 3rd column can sometimes contain pipe(s).

For that, you can use the regex:

```
(?:^(?:[^|\n]*\|){2}|(?!^)\G)[^|\n]*\K\|
```

And replace with space.

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dO9wX1/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^|]*\|[^|]*\|)(?:([^|]*$)|([^|]*)\|([^|]*$))
```

Try this.Replace by `$1$2$3$4`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/29